# How to move armature origin without moving bone world positions?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

Is there any way to move the armature origin to another position without moving the bones world positions?

I mean like moving origins only inside of mesh objects.

Here's the option for mesh objects. But it doesn't work for armatures:

[image]

Thank you
Chris

Comment: I wasn't able to understand the question exactly. Do you want to, like, have the same effect which happens when we go to edit mode of the object and change the position of the geometry, and it still doesn't affect the actual locationn of the object itself?

Comment: About the same. You can select any mesh object, and move the origin without moving the vertices in Blender. It's the opposite way, you're describing.
I'm asking for a way doing this with armatures. Move an armatures origin without moving its bone positions.

Comment: I saw the edit. It does work in my case though. Of course not in the pose mode. But in object mode, it works. I mean like in obj mode that is the pivot point. But in pose mode it's the head (or tail, I don't remember which is which)

Comment: Oh yes! Maybe I've overseen something. Thank you!
Edit: Ah i see. In my scene the armature transformation was locker. That answers everything... :)

Comment: Don't hesitate to post the answer of your own question, it's extra points for you, and more visibility for anyone having the same issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works. Basically the same like moving mesh origins:

[image]